# Как удалить строку из таблицы БД с помощью Ajax, без перезагрузки страницы?

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Нужно реализовать удаление данных без перезагрузки страницы подскажите пожалуйста как отправить ID записи в файл func_admin.php для того чтобы скрипт сработал:

```
if (isset($_POST['delete_id'])) {

   $delid = $_POST['delete_id'];

   $sqldelttech = ("DELETE FROM `spravtech` WHERE `spravtech`.`id_spravtech` = ?");

   $quwerydel = $db->prepare($sqldelttech);
   $quwerydel->execute([$delid]);
}
```

Разметка таблицы:

```
 <div class="container-fluid" style="margin-top: 20px;">
            <table class="table table-sm  table-bordered table-hover" style="font-size: 12px;">
                <thead class="table-secondary">
                    <tr>
                        <th>№</th>
                        <th>ОВД</th>
                        <th>ПОДРАЗДЕЛЕНИЕ</th>
                        <th>ТИП ТЕХНИКИ</th>
                        <th>ПРОИЗВОДИТЕЛЬ</th>
                        <th>МОДЕЛЬ</th>
                        <th>СЕРИЙНЫЙ НОМЕР</th>
                        <th>ИНВЕНТАРНЫЙ НОМЕР</th>
                        <th>ВВОД В ЭКСПЛУАТАЦИЮ</th>
                        <th>ДЕЙСТВИЯ</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody class="table-light">
                    <?php if (!empty($restechinfo)) {
                        foreach ($restechinfo as $resinfo) { ?>
                            <tr>
                                <td><?php echo $resinfo->id_spravtech; ?></td>
                                <td><a href="#"><?php echo  $resinfo->name_ovdrb; ?></a></td>
                                <td style="max-width: 150px;"><?php echo  $resinfo->name_subdivision; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo  $resinfo->type; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo  $resinfo->manufacture; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo  $resinfo->model; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo  $resinfo->serial_number; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo  $resinfo->inventary_number; ?></td>
                                <td><?php echo  $resinfo->date; ?></td>
                                <td>
                                    <div class="bttnaction">
                                        <div class="bttnactiongroup">
                                            <a id="delete_id<?php echo $resinfo->id_spravtech; ?>" onclick="return confirm('Вы действительно хотите удалить запись № <?php echo $resinfo->id_spravtech; ?>?')" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
                                                <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
                                            </a>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>
                                </td>
                            </tr>
                        <?php } ?>
                    <?php } else { ?>
                        <tr>
                            <td colspan=10 class="text-center table-danger">НЕТ ДАННЫХ</td>
                        </tr>
                    <?php } ?>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
```

Comment: мне кажется если загуглить ajax, то ответ будет в первом миллиарде результатов

Comment: Если кажется, то загуглите пожалуйста и скиньте ссылку ответом, я вопрос задал не для того чтобы видеть остроумные комментарии по типу: "гугл в помощь", нет желания помочь, можно просто пролистать вопрос, для чего вы написали это?

Answer (score 1):

Писал на скорую руку, просьба тапками не кидать.

`file.html`

```html
...
<a id="delete_id<?php echo $resinfo->id_spravtech; ?>" onclick="return doDelete(this);" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm">
    <i class="fa fa-trash"></i>
</a>
...
```

`file.js`

```js
function doDelete( o ) {
    var id = $(o).attr('id').replace(/^delete_id/,''); //Получаем ID удаляемой записи из атрибута `id`
    if ( confirm('Вы действительно хотите удалить запись № '+id+'?')

        //на всякий случай (вдруг процесс отправки запроса серверу и получения ответа займет длительное время)
        //отключаем возможность второй раз кликнуть на эту же ссылку
        $(o).attr('data-onclick', $(o).attr('onclick'));
        $(o).removeAttr('onclick');

        $.ajax({
            url: 'func_admin.php',
            type: 'POST',
            data: 'delete_id'+id,
            cache: false,
            error: function(req, text, error) {
                alert( 'Ошибка сервера: '+error );
                //Ошибка сервера, восстанавливаем возможность клика на ссылке
                $(o).attr('onclick', $(o).attr('data-onclick'));
                $(o).removeAttr('data-onclick');
            },
            success: function ( data ) {
                if ( data && typeof data.success !== typeof undefined && typeof data.success !== false ) {
                    if ( !data.success ) {
                        alert( 'Удаление невозможно!\nОшибка:'+data.message );
                        //Ошибка приудалении (БД или еще что), восстанавливаем возможность клика на ссылке
                        $(o).attr('onclick', $(o).attr('data-onclick'));
                        $(o).removeAttr('data-onclick');
                    } else {
                        alert( 'Запись успешно удалена.');
                        //так как запись удалена - то возможность клика на этой же ссылке не восстанавливаем - зачем серверу лишние запросы на уже удаленные записи?
                    }
                } else {
                    alert( 'Некорректный ответ сервера!');
                    $(o).attr('onclick', $(o).attr('data-onclick'));
                    $(o).removeAttr('data-onclick');
                }
            },
        });
    }
    return false;
}
```

`func_admin.php`

```php
$response = new stdClass();
$response->success = false;
$response->messsage = 'Не указан ID удаляемой записи!';
if (is_array( $_POST ) && count( $_POST ) > 0 && isset( $_POST['delete_id'] ) && is_numeric( $_POST['delete_id'] ) && intval( $_POST['delete_id'] ) > 0 ) {

   $delid = intval($_POST['delete_id']); //при условии что конечно это у вас integer, а не алиас какой-нибудь вообще
   //По-хорошему тут все нужно обернуть в try ... catch чтобы отлавливать ошибки выполнения sql-запроса
   //мало-ли - связь до Бд упала, запрос кривой, записи такой нет и тд итп
   //и в случае возникновения такой ошибки пихать ее текст в $response->message

   $sqldelttech = ("DELETE FROM `spravtech` WHERE `spravtech`.`id_spravtech` = ?");
   $quwerydel = $db->prepare($sqldelttech);
   $quwerydel->execute([$delid]);
   //Если запрос успешно выполнился
   $response->messsage = 'Запись успешно удалена!';
   $response->success = true;
}

return json_encode( $response );
```

Comment: VS Code говорит что фигурные скобки перед return false; и после него неправильно стоят

Comment: и в консоли ошибки: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier , admin.php:327 Uncaught ReferenceError: doDelete is not defined
   at HTMLAnchorElement.onclick (admin.php:327:124)

Comment: Я уже писал ".. на скорую руку". И Вы вроде просили помощи в понимании а не полностью готовый, написанный за Вас, рабочий код.

Comment: я спросил:  "как отправить?" Вы написали код за что я очень благодарен, но он не работает, поэтому я спрашиваю у вас по поводу ошибок.

Comment: А говорили "программист"... :) 
Уберите "}" перед `return false`. Подключите `file.js` внутри `file.html` либо вставьте код `file.js` внутрь `file.html` -в этом случае не забудьте заключить его в <script> ... </script>

Comment: не работает, гугл тоже не помог((((..........